# List of phones that support media queries?

Tags: mobile, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Majority of mobile devices support media queries for screen width?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19531/majority-of-mobile-devices-support-media-queries-for-screen-width)

Is there any resource that lists which phones support media queries?

I'm optimizing my site. It works fine on iPhone and the Android I've tested with, but now I'm using emulators to test more devices. My media queries seem to be ignored by the Blackberry 9630, but it is quite an old phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good resource for this is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) ([CSS3 Media Queries](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries)). I have no personal experience with Blackberry but I found [this table](http://docs.blackberry.com/nl-nl/developers/deliverables/11844/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp) on the Blackberry site. Seems like you need at least [Blackberry OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS#Current_versions) version 4.7.1 or higher.

Comment: caniuse seems to be down...

Comment: caniuse is working for me at the moment